# Firefox input field height does not match font size

Tags: firefox

As shown in the screenshot:

[image]

I have tried to change font family, font size, minimal font size, and restart firefox in safe mode,  nothing seemed to help.

So far this problem only appears in stackexchange sites.

I am using firefox 25 on ubuntu 13.10.

---

To reproduce this issue, open this page: https://superuser.com/questions/ask

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a page where we can see this issue? Could you also provide step by step instructions to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Can you also please check if this happens in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). If the new profile is okay, you can then delete it, and [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) from the current profile. [Profile Manager](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager)